# Mysql on duplicate key update - how to make it so that it does not insert new rows?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, key

I am using insert on duplicate key update for updating the status of many orders.

However if I enter an id that does not exist, mysql creates a new order.

Is there any way to NOT create a new order?

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO
`order`
( id, status )
VALUES (1, 'COMPLETE'), (2, 'COMPLETE'), (3, 'INVALID')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
status = VALUES(status)
```

Comment: Yes, use UPDATE not insert.

Comment: If I use update, I would not be able to update multiple rows in one query

Answer (score 0):

Add backtracks for table name

```
INSERT INTO `order`( id, status ) VALUES (1, '43534'), (2, '434'), (3,'345345') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = VALUES(status)
```